# Duplicating data in Dataframe based on max count

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
dfaugment = dftrain.sort_values('text', ascending=False).groupby('Category')
countdict = dict(dfaugment['Category'].count())
countdictmax = max(countdict.values())
shortdict = {}
for key, value in countdict.items():
    if value <= countdictmax:
    shortdict[key] = countdictmax - value
```

I'm trying to generate duplicate rows for the different Category fields based on the max count of the Category fields.

For example:

```
Category | text 
Shoes | "aasdb"
Shoes | "frrrd"
Shoes | "ertbt"
Shoes | "erbete"
Shoes | "ervsss"
Sticks | "14345"
Sticks | "33445"
```

should become

```
Category | text 
Shoes | "aasdb"
Shoes | "frrrd"
Shoes | "ertbt"
Shoes | "erbete"
Shoes | "ervsss"
Sticks | "14345"
Sticks | "33445"
Sticks | "14345" #new row (duplicated from above data) 
Sticks | "33445" #new row (duplicated from above data) 
Sticks | "14345" #new row (duplicated from above data)
```

Comment: Does it matter how the data is duplicated? Would a simple forwardfill operation suffice?

Comment: Would be great if there is an option to random.sample() the data but I'm thinking forwardfill is enough based on what I'm reading on the internet now, and that is actually the next part of the problem I'm trying to solve. 1. is to randomise the sample selected for duplication, 2. is to randomise the words in all the text of that Category combined to create augmented data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try of duplicating the individual grouped dataframes by considering the maximum group value,

```
def DuplicateRows(x,group_max):
    Count = int(np.ceil((group_max - len(x))/len(x))) +1
    return pd.concat([x]*Count)[:group_max]

group_max = df.groupby('Category').apply(len).max()
df.groupby('Category',group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: DuplicateRows(x,group_max))
```

Out:

```
    Category    text
0   Shoes   "aasdb"
1   Shoes   "frrrd"
2   Shoes   "ertbt"
3   Shoes   "erbete"
4   Shoes   "ervsss"
5   Sticks  "14345"
6   Sticks  "33445"
5   Sticks  "14345"
6   Sticks  "33445"
5   Sticks  "14345"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the *repeating* fill using [itertools.cycle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) & `zip`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [('Shoes',"aasdb"), 
     ('Shoes',"frrrd"),
     ('Shoes',"ertbt"),
     ('Shoes',"erbete"),
     ('Shoes',"ervsss"),
     ('Sticks',"14345"),
     ('Sticks',"33445")], 
    columns=['Category', 'text']
)
```

First we find the max_size, then we construct our list of tuples & pass to the DataFrame constructor.

```
max_size = df.groupby('Category').size().max()
pd.DataFrame(
    [(a, b) 
     for k in df.Category.drop_duplicates()
     for a, b in zip([k]*max_size, cycle(df.text[df.Category==k]))]
    , columns = df.columns
)
```

This outputs:

```
  Category    text
0    Shoes   aasdb
1    Shoes   frrrd
2    Shoes   ertbt
3    Shoes  erbete
4    Shoes  ervsss
5   Sticks   14345
6   Sticks   33445
7   Sticks   14345
8   Sticks   33445
9   Sticks   14345
```

---

variant 1:

> I'm thinking forwardfill is enough

to forwardfill, use [`iterools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) on `Category`, but **do not** `cycle` on `text` & then `ffill`

```
pd.DataFrame(
    [(a, b) 
     for k in df.Category.drop_duplicates()
     for a, b in zip_longest([k]*max_size, df.text[df.Category==k])]
    , columns = df.columns).ffill()
```

This outputs:

```
  Category    text
0    Shoes   aasdb
1    Shoes   frrrd
2    Shoes   ertbt
3    Shoes  erbete
4    Shoes  ervsss
5   Sticks   14345
6   Sticks   33445
7   Sticks   33445
8   Sticks   33445
9   Sticks   33445
```

---

variant 2:

> randomise the sample selected for duplication

I'm not sure *exactly* what is meant here, but here's a way to get a *random* fill.

This starts similar to the forward fill.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    [(a, b) 
     for k in df.Category.drop_duplicates()
     for a, b in zip_longest([k]*max_size, df.text[df.Category==k])]
    , columns = df.columns
)
```

Next for each group get a sample of `text` of size `max_size` & stack them. And coalesce using [`pandas.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.combine_first.html)

```
fill = pd.concat(
    [df.text[df.Category==k].sample(max_size, replace=True)
     for k in df.Category.drop_duplicates()]
).reset_index(drop=True)
df2.text = df2.text.combine_first(fill)
```

example df2 output (may differ for you as I have not set a seed for the sample)

```
  Category    text
0    Shoes   aasdb
1    Shoes   frrrd
2    Shoes   ertbt
3    Shoes  erbete
4    Shoes  ervsss
5   Sticks   14345
6   Sticks   33445
7   Sticks   14345
8   Sticks   14345
9   Sticks   33445
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I'm having trouble converting the code to more than 1 column for first solution. `AssertionError: 4 columns passed, passed data had 2 columns` Possible to make the solution modular?

Comment: i'm not sure I can help without seeing what you have tried or what your real data looks like.